# How to execute dpkg-query in chef 14?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

Can someone let me know how can I execute the below command using chef-14?

`dpkg-query --status log-agent | grep -q  '^Version: 212121`

I am able to find a [dpkg_package](https://docs.chef.io/resource_dpkg_package.html) resource. But not anything for `dpkg-query`. I intend to use the above command in `include_recipe` so using `guards` is not an option for me.

If possible I would like to avoid `shell_out`.

Answer (score 0):

you can execute system command in many ways... from your question it is not clear whether you want to grub the output of the command or just use it a [guard](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#guards).

if you only want to execute it, you can use [`execute`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_execute.html), [`bash`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_bash.html) and even [`ruby_block`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_ruby_block.html) to achieve it.

Comment: I need to know if the `log-agent` version installed is `212121`

Comment: @tuk: and if it is not `212121` you probably want to do (or not do) something... so use a guard....

Comment: I want to do `include_recipe` if the version is not 212121 . I think `guard` does not work with `include_receipe`.